# Ideas on the ways to integrate $\int \tan^2( x)\sec^3( x) dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I would proceed by thus , let $y = [\sec (x)]^2 $

then

$$dy = 2 \cdot \sec(x) \cdot \sec(x) \cdot \tan(x) \cdot dx = 2 \cdot ( \sec (x))^2 \cdot \tan(x) \cdot dx $$

so, 
$$
2 \tan^2(x) \sec^2 (x) dx = \sec(x) \cdot \tan(x) \cdot dy = y(y-1)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot dy
$$

since $$\sec(x) = y^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and by considering
positive square roots only $\tan y = ( \sec^2(x) - 1)^{1/2} = (y - 1)^{1/2}$. Thus the substitution $y = \sec^2 x$ yields
$$
2 \int \tan^2 (x) \sec^3(x) dx = \int (y(y - 1) )^{1/2} dy
$$
and this later form  can be reduced to  the  standard form  $\int(z^2 - a^2)^{1/2} dz$ since 
$$
y(y-1)=(y-(1/2))^2 - (1/2)^2 . 
$$
What  are the  other ways to integrate this expression, except for the substitution

$\tan^2(x)^2=\sec (x)^2 -1$ which gives 
$$
\sec^5(x) - \sec^3 (x)
$$
in the integrand which I quite don't like.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but all I can think of so far is some integration by parts ugliness...

Comment: Perhaps ugliness cannot be avoided! Use reduction formula for Sec^n(x) and keep working. It can be done, and the result does not have to be cute.

Comment: Now I think I know what's throwing me.  The sec exponent is odd and the tan exponent is even.  Any other combination would be 100 times simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let you want to solve $\int R\big(\sin(x),\cos(x)\big)dx$ and you know that $$R\big(\sin(x),-\cos(x)\big)\equiv -R\big(\sin(x),\cos(x)\big)$$ then you can take $\sin(x)=t$ for a good substitution. We have here $$\int \tan^2(x)\sec^3(x)dx=\int \frac{\sin^2(x)dx}{\cos^5(x)}$$ and we can see the above statement is true for the last integrand. By taking $\sin(x)=t$, we have $$\int\frac{t^2}{(1-t^2)^3}dt$$ which can be solve by fractions method.

Comment: @ Babak Sorouh                                                    Hm, I like that approach.

Comment: @Souvik: If you have $\int R\big(\sin(x),\cos(x)\big)dx$ where in $$R\big(-\sin(x),\cos(x)\big)\equiv -R\big(\sin(x),\cos(x)\big)$$ then you can take $\cos(x)=t$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by intgration by parts

$ I=\int tan^2 x \cdot sec^3x \space dx$
$=\int (sec^2 x-1)\cdot sec^3 x \space dx$
$=\int sec^5 x \space dx-\int sec^3 x \space dx$
$=sec^3 x \cdot tan x-\int 3sec^2 x \cdot sec x tan x \cdot tan x \space dx-\int sec^3 x \space dx  $
$= sec^3x \cdot tanx-3I-I_1$
$ or, 4I= sec^3x \cdot tanx-I_1$

We can now find out the second integral

$I_1=\int sec^3 x ~dx=\int sec x ~sec^2x~dx=sec x~tan x-\int sec x~(sec^2 x-1)dx=sec x~tanx-I_1+\int sec x~dx$

$or, 2I_1=secx~tan x+ln|sec x+tan x|$

Now back to original problem:

$I={1 \over 4}sec^3x\cdot tanx-{1 \over 8}(sec x~tan x+ln|sec x+tan x|)+c$

Answer (score -1):

The answer for $\int \tan^2 (x)\sec^3 (x) dx$:
[image: The answer for integral of tan^2 (x)sec^3 (x) . dx]